# Error 6013: The table/view does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, edmx

OKay, I have stuck with these errors for a week, I have googled a lot of solutions, but they all seem not like my situation.

There are two warning errors and multiple warnings after I changed one of the data types in my database and updated Models from the database.

The warnings are:
Message 1   Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'HeaderSelectedCssClass' is not a valid attribute of element 'AccordionPane'.

```
->Warning   17  The variable 'f' is declared but never used 
->Warning   15  The variable 'ex' is declared but never used    
->Warning   20  The variable 'e' is declared but never used 

->Warning   29  Error 6013: The table/view 'C:\USERS\\APP_DATA\CMSDB.MDF.dbo.View' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.   

->Warning   28  Error 6013: The table/view 'C:\USERS\\APP_DATA\CMSDB.MDF.dbo.totalOTHours' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.
```

Follow the error I have found the exact file in my project and I realize these two are not even a table.

So, how should I deal with it?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are `CMSDB.dbo.View` & `CMSDB.dbo.totalOTHours` are SQL views? Note that you need tables with PK enabled to be mapped on EDMX.

Comment: FYI:CMSDB.dbo.View & CMSDB.dbo.totalOTHours are under my SQL>Views and I checked all my existing tables have PK, Thanks!